# SVG: Отображать textPath всегда в горизонтальном положении

Tags: html, вёрстка, svg

Мне необходимо отображать текст на линиях сделанных через `<path/>`, но сами линии расположены под случайными углами (но сами линии всегда прямые если важно). Как можно сделать так, чтобы при любом положении `<textPath/>` отображался всегда горизонтально? Из того что не сработало: разделение на `<tspan/>` и  CSS-свойство `text-orientation` (возможно неправильно использовал)
На картинке ниже привел то, как выглядят линии сейчас. Мне нужно чтобы текст лежал строго горизонтально при любом положении стрелки

[image: Так выглядит текст на линиях сейчас]

Текст на линиях должен будет выглядеть так **при любом положении самой стрелки** (т.е. не повернут):
[image: Так он должен выглядеть потом в любом положении]

Comment: Добавьте код своей попытки или нарисуйте картинку, как это должно выглядеть. Слова ведь понимаются по разному

Comment: Добавил картинку и пояснения. Вот [похожий](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535418/horizontal-text-on-path) вопрос с англоязычной версии сайта, однако мне нужно, если это возможно, просто повернуть текст, чтобы он распологался по горизонтали справа налево (а не выровнять буквы отдельно).

Comment: то есть текст должен быть всегда горизонтально. Сейчас добавлю вариант ответа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Появились новые идеи,

как можно ещё проще решить вопрос - **горизонтального положения текста при любом наклоне линий.**

*#1. Так как в команде  `textPath`*

```
<textPath href="#txtPath2" startOffset="5" side="left"  >
      <tspan  dy="0">Text on Lines Test 2 </tspan>
    </textPath>
```

Для расположения текста всегда используется `path`, который должен быть прямой, горизонтальной линией, то возникает вопрос, а зачем он тогда вообще нужен?
Проще заменить `<textPath>` на `<text>`

Команда - `<text x="100" y="100" font-size="18px">Text on Lines Test 1 </text>`, итак всегда располагает текст горизонтально.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >  
<defs>
    <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" orient="auto">
            <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill: #000000;" />
    </marker>
</defs> 

  <text x="100" y="100" font-size="18px">Text on Lines Test 1 </text>    
     <text x="300" y="200" font-size="18px">Text on Lines Test 2 </text> 
       <text x="130" y="350" font-size="18px">Text on Lines Test 3 </text>   
 
    <g marker-end="url(#markerArrow)" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3">
      <line id="line1" x1="40"  y1="40" x2="350" y2="350"  />
      <line id="line2" x1="240"  y1="40" x2="350" y2="400"  /> 
      <line id="line3" x1="40"  y1="350" x2="300" y2="400"  /> 
    </g>  
</svg>
```

*#2. Использование тега `<title>`*

При использовании этого тега выводится текстовая подсказка, которая всегда расположена горизонтально.

```
<g id="line1"> 
        <title>Text on Lines Test 1</title> 
      <line  x1="40"  y1="40" x2="350" y2="350"  />
</g>
```

Необходимо только навести курсор на линию:

```css
#line1,#line2,#line3 {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width:3px;
transition:all 0.4s;
}
#line1:hover,#line2:hover,#line3:hover {
stroke:red;
stroke-width:6px;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      
     width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >  

<defs>

    <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" orient="auto">
            <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill: #000000;" />
    </marker>
</defs> 
 
    <g marker-end="url(#markerArrow)">
      <g id="line1"> 
        <title>Text on Lines Test 1</title> 
      <line  x1="40"  y1="40" x2="350" y2="350"  />
      </g> 
          <g id="line2"> 
            <title>Text on Lines Test 2</title> 
             <line id="line2" x1="240"  y1="40" x2="350" y2="400"  /> 
          </g>
      <g id="line2"> 
        <title>Text on Lines Test 3</title> 
          <line id="line3" x1="40"  y1="350" x2="300" y2="400"  /> 
       </g>
    </g>  
</svg>
```

Comment: @Kli Если ответы вам были полезны, не забудьте выбрать ответ и отметить его решением

Answer (score 1):

Команда `textPath` размещает текст вдоль пути указанного в `href="#txtPath"`
Она не поворачивается, поэтому, чтобы сделать текст горизонтальным, нужно, чтобы путь `href="#txtPath"` был горизонтальным.

Можно решить вашу задачу добавлением линий, которые будут идти наклонно под любым углом, а к концу этих линий можно присоединить горизонтальный текст, указанный в `textPath`

Пример с одной наклонной линией и одним горизонтальным текстом:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      
     width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >  

         <!-- Горизонтальная линия вдоль которой идёт текст -->
<path id="txtPath"  d="M150 40 h300" fill="none" stroke="black" /> 
         <!-- Наклонная линия -->
 <line x1="40"  y1="400" x2="150" y2="40" fill="none" stroke="black" />
  <text font-size="16px" >
    <textPath href="#txtPath" startOffset="0" side="left"  >
      <tspan  dy="-10">Текст находится на линии  c id="txtPath </tspan>
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Несколько линий:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      
     width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >  

<path id="txtPath1"  d="M150 40 h350" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
   <path id="txtPath2"  d="M250 100 h350" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
     <path id="txtPath3"  d="M250 200 h350" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
 

 <line id="line1" x1="40"  y1="400" x2="150" y2="40" fill="none" stroke="black" />
    <line id="line2" x1="40"  y1="400" x2="250" y2="100" fill="none" stroke="black" /> 
      <line id="line3" x1="40"  y1="400" x2="250" y2="200" fill="none" stroke="black" />
  <text font-size="18px" >
    <textPath href="#txtPath1" startOffset="0" side="left"  >
      <tspan  dy="-10">Текст находится на линии  c id="txtPath </tspan>
    </textPath>
   
     <textPath href="#txtPath2" startOffset="0" side="left"  >
      <tspan  dy="0">Другой текст на линии  </tspan>
    </textPath> 
       <textPath href="#txtPath3" startOffset="0" side="left"  >
      <tspan  dy="0">Третий текст на линии  </tspan>
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Если вам нужны стрелки на концах линий, то можно добавить маркеры

```
<marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" 
     orient="auto">
            <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill: #000000;" />
</marker>
```

*Пример наклонных линий с маркерами*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      
     width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >  

<defs>

    <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" orient="auto">
            <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill: #000000;" />
    </marker>
</defs> 

<path id="txtPath1"  d="M150 40 h350" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
   <path id="txtPath2"  d="M250 100 h350" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
     <path id="txtPath3"  d="M250 200 h350" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
 
    <g marker-end="url(#markerArrow)" fill="none" stroke="black">
      <line id="line1" x1="40"  y1="400" x2="150" y2="40"  />
      <line id="line2" x1="40"  y1="400" x2="250" y2="100"  /> 
      <line id="line3" x1="40"  y1="400" x2="250" y2="200"  /> 
    </g>  
      
  <text font-size="18px" >
    <textPath href="#txtPath1" startOffset="0" side="left"  >
      <tspan  dy="-10">Текст находится на линии  c id="txtPath </tspan>
    </textPath>
   
     <textPath href="#txtPath2" startOffset="5" side="left"  >
      <tspan  dy="0">Другой текст на линии  </tspan>
    </textPath> 
       <textPath href="#txtPath3" startOffset="4" side="left"  >
      <tspan  dy="0">Третий текст на линии  </tspan>
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

*Пример как на рисунке в вопросе*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      
     width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >  

<defs>

    <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" orient="auto">
            <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill: #000000;" />
    </marker>
</defs> 

<path id="txtPath1"  d="M95 100 h350" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
   <path id="txtPath2"  d="M300 200 h350" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
     <path id="txtPath3"  d="M130 350 h350" fill="none" stroke="none" /> 
 
    <g marker-end="url(#markerArrow)" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3">
      <line id="line1" x1="40"  y1="40" x2="350" y2="350"  />
      <line id="line2" x1="240"  y1="40" x2="350" y2="400"  /> 
      <line id="line3" x1="40"  y1="350" x2="300" y2="400"  /> 
    </g>  
      
  <text font-size="18px" >
    <textPath href="#txtPath1" startOffset="0" side="left"  >
      <tspan  dy="-10">Text on Lines Test 1 </tspan>
    </textPath>
   
     <textPath href="#txtPath2" startOffset="5" side="left"  >
      <tspan  dy="0">Text on Lines Test 2 </tspan>
    </textPath>  
     <textPath href="#txtPath3" startOffset="5" side="left"  >
      <tspan  dy="0">Text on Lines Test 3 </tspan>
    </textPath>
      
  </text>
</svg>
```